# Initialization of tf.contrib.data.Iterator with tf.estimator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

How one should initialize `tf.contrib.data.Iterator` in case `tf.estimator.Estimator` also is used?

One of the problems is that input graph *(the part of tf graph handling input)* supposed to be defined in `intput_fn()` - beacause tf.estimator creates seprate graph.

This requirement makes it hard to access the iterator `init ops` and pass them `to tf.estimator` (passing the ops can be done when calling `train/evaluate/predict` in forms of hooks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to wrap your `input_fn` inside another function that sets up a simple SessionRunHook `init_hook`. All the ops are defined inside `input_fn`, which gets called in the same graph as the rest of your model, but from it you can set the `iterator_init_op` as an attribute on `init_hook`.

```
def get_input_fn(mode="train"):
    init_hook = IteratorInitHook()

    def input_fn():
        ...
        iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
        init_hook.iterator_init_op = iterator.initializer

    return input_fn, init_hook

class IteratorInitHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):

    def after_create_session(self, session, coord):
        session.run(self.iterator_init_op)
```

Now when constructing an `Experiment`, you can get these input functions and and init hooks, which get called when train/eval sessions are created. It should work equivalently with `estimator.train`.

```
train_input_fn, train_init_hook = get_input_fn("train")
test_input_fn, test_init_hook = get_input_fn("test")

return tf.contrib.learn.Experiment(
    estimator=estimator,
    train_input_fn=train_input_fn,
    eval_input_fn=test_input_fn,
    train_monitors=[train_init_hook],
    eval_hooks=[test_init_hook],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `SessionManager` as hook would solve the same.

```
sm = tf.train.SessionManager(local_init_op=iterator_init_op)
...
estimator = tf.train.Estimator(...)
estimator.train(input_fn, hooks=[sm], steps=None, max_steps=None)
```

Comment: The problem is with passing the init op to estimator.train.
You're not supposed to have access to `init_op` in your hook code (beacuse it should be defined in init_fn. 
And init_fn cannot (!) be called before - beacause of 1 graph requirement.
What I did is saving init_op into collections under preset name and then read collection in the hook you told me about. I will think about it more, expand your answer to give full answer.